# How can I make each line from a file a sublist, of a list that encompasses the whole file?

Tags: python, list, sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am able to turn each line of the file into a list, however, I want each line to be its own sublist: eg. `[['7', '3'], ['0', '0'], ['7', '6']]`

I tried:

```
SampleData = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(filename)]
```

and this is the part of the txt file I have:

```
7 3
0 0
7 6
0 2
4 7
1 7
6 1
2 3
```

what I have been trying is `rList = []`
and then `rList.append(list(file.readlines()))`

thanks !!

Comment: UPDATE: each pair of of numbers is on a separate line!!!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split might be useful.

Comment: just change to: `SampleData = [line.rstrip('\n').split() for line in open(filename)]`

Comment: @Tomerikoo   I tried this: 
 SampleData = [line.rstrip('\n').split() for line in open(filename)]

    rList = []

    rList.append(list(SampleData[12:27])) 

but now im getting a triple bracket around the outside, how should I go about fixing this? eg.[[['7','3'],['0', '0'], ['1','1']]]

Comment: @Tomerikoo just edited the comment! sorry I submitted it before completing it

Comment: This is the way you define it... `SampleData[12:27]` is already a list of lists and then you append it inside another list... so just do `rList = SampleData[12:27]`

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

- [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) - Returns a list of strings after breaking the given string by the specified separator.
- [rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip) - Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed.
- readlines() reads until EOF using readline() and returns a list containing the lines.

`ab.text` file

```
7 3
0 0
7 6
0 2
4 7
1 7
6 1
2 3
```

**Ex.**

```
with open('ab.text') as f:
  data = [x.rstrip('\n').split(" ") for x in f.readlines() ]
print(data)
```

**O/P:**

```
[['7', '3'], ['0', '0'], ['7', '6'], ['0', '2'], ['4', '7'], ['1', '7'], ['6', '1'], ['2', '3']]
```